# Git checout <SHA> *filename results in "pathspect did not match any files" error

Tags: git

Is it possible to checkout a file(s) using only part of its name, and replacing unknown part with * (asterisk), same as I would when using git show or git diff.

e.g.

```
git checkout <SHA> -- *.snippet
```

or

```
git checkout <SHA> *.snippet
```

both result in

> error: pathspec '*.snippet' did not match any file(s) known to git.

yet using a full path/name works. There surely must be a way to do that?

Comment: I see an immediate problem with this, which is namely what would happen if more than one file were to match the pattern?  Couldn't you just find the file first using `grep`, then call `git checkout` with the full path as you normally would?

Comment: This works fine for me. `git checkout HEAD^ -- 'file*'; git status` results in `new file: file2` (in the index, ready to commit) when `HEAD` contains just `file1` while `HEAD^` contains both `file1` and `file2`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only <SHA1> | grep '.snippet$' | xargs git checkout <SHA1>
```